# passing argument 1 of strlen from incompatible pointer type

Tags: objective-c

I am taking values from array and saving it in linked list as follows:

```
NSString *formataddr=[RestaurantList objectAtIndex:0];
node1->formattedAddress = (char*)malloc(strlen(formataddr)*sizeof(char)+1);
```

where `formattedaddress` is char array. But I'm getting error

> passing argument 1 of strlen from incompatible pointer type

Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `strlen()` with `NSString *`, you have to use `[formataddr length]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[formataddr length]
```

instead of strlen(formataddr)

NSString isn't supported by strlen().

Comment: Or rather, `strlen()` does not support `NSString *`.